# AnyView blocks View updates

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple view:

This view is wrapped by another view that has an observed object.

Such code doesn't update the view:

```
struct SomeView: View {
 @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel
var body: some View {
let text = viewModel.text
return ForEach(0..<1) { AnyView(text) }
}
}
```

but it works:

```
return ForEach(0..<1) { text }
```

Is it bug? Can I use AnyView for ForEach view?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, when I asked a question I found a solution:

You should use ForEach `ForEach(0..<1, id: \.self) { AnyView(text) }`